# Screens don't render on material bottom tab navigator since upgrading to Expo SDK 43

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v6

I have an expo project which was SDK v42 and everything has been working fine and the app is currently in production. However, after upgrading to expo SDK 43, Stack navigators that are passed on the Material bottom tab are not rendered and only shows a blank screen. I have made a dummy project with the following github repo: https://github.com/kamrul91111/sdk,

[image]

[image]

The screens in the Stack Navigator passed to the material bottom tab navigator work the first time, but when I go to another screen on the bottom tab and come back, the screens aren't rendered anymore.

This issue can be fixed by downgrading to expo v42 or just using Bottom Tab Navigator instead of the material bottom tab navigator. What's the issue here? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you haven't figured it out yet, this bug has apparently been fixed if you upgrade to react-native >0.65.0 (I haven't personally tested this yet though)

There is also a simple fix if you don't want to upgrade:
software-mansion/react-native-screens#1197 (comment)

Basically just wrap your stack navigator with
<View style={{flex: 1}} collapsable={false}>

Comment: I followed your advice, but Expo SDK 44/43 seems not to be compatible with react-native >0.65: `Warning: Invalid version react-native@0.68.1 for expo sdkVersion 44.0.0. Use react-native@0.64.3`. Is it better to update anyway or to fix manually?

Comment: Since updating to >0.65 is not recommended, yet (https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/react-native-releases.md), I decided to use `<View style={{flex: 1}} collapsable={false}>` around all my stackNavigators .

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was passing the property `sceneAnimationEnabled={false}` to the Navigator, looks like it could be a problem with the animation when switching between screens

```
<BottomTab.Navigator sceneAnimationEnabled={false}>
```